# Address of environment variable different for each directory

Tags: linux, memory, bash

I'm writing a return-to-libc attack for a school project. My script retrieves the system(), exit() and shell addresses as follows (it's a sh script that calls some c programs):

Create the environment variable for the xh shell:
    `export egg=/bin/xh`

Retrieve the address of the xh shell: `printf("%p\n", getenv("egg"));`

Get the address of system(): `void (*system_addr)(int) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "system");`

Get the address of exit(): `void (*exit_addr)(int) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "exit");`

I then overflow the buffer with the correct amount of filler + address of `system()` + address of `exit()` + address of `/bin/xh`.

The exploit is in a folder called `/vuln_programs`. We can't write to this directory so I'm working on a local copy in my own directory on the server.

The problem is that when I run the script in my working directory on my local copy ( `./vuln_program`), the xh shell is dropped correctly. But when I run the script in my working directory on `/vuln_programs/vuln_program` nothing happens.

My guess is that this is because for some reason the address of the egg is not the same anymore even though my script puts/gets it in/from the environment. 
Am I right in this assumption and how can I resolve this?

It might be important to note that all binaries in `/vuln_programs` have a setuid-bit set.

Comment: Try to use full absolute paths always instead. Not really sure what is your problem but if there is no permission problem... maybe you can put entire code...